# Creating a Random javascript array from an HTML input field

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function

I have basic HTML form that asks for a number between 1 and 10. Based on that number I want to create a new array. For now the code shows an alert box of the new created array, but eventually it will be a table that displays the results. The current array has 10 values and I want it generate a new array randomly. I think I have it and just missing one thing or maybe a few.

```
function createRandomArray () {

var numOfGamesElement = document.getElementById("numOfGames");
var numOfGames = numOfGamesElement.value;

var gamesPicked [];

  const boardGames = ["UNO", "Monopoly", "Clue", "Pandemic", "Catan", "Articulate!", "Codenames", "Fallout", "Candy Land", "Scrabble"];


let gamesPicked = boardGames[Math.floor(Math.random() * boardGames.length)];

for(let i = 0; i < numOfGames; i++){
  gamesPicked.push(i);
}
  alert(gamesPicked.join("\n"));
//createTable(gamesPicked)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works but does not address that the random function can pick duplicates.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script>
function createRandomArray () {
    var numOfGamesElement = document.getElementById("numOfGames");
    var numOfGames = numOfGamesElement.value;

    const boardGames = ["UNO", "Monopoly", "Clue", "Pandemic", "Catan", "Articulate!", "Codenames", "Fallout", "Candy Land", "Scrabble"];

    var gamePicked;
    var gamesPicked = {};
    for(let i = 0; i < numOfGames; i++){
      gamePicked = boardGames[Math.floor(Math.random() * boardGames.length)];
      gamesPicked[i] = gamePicked;
      alert(gamesPicked[i]);
    }
    // could build table here
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<label>Number of games (1 to 10):
<input id="numOfGames">
</label>
<button onclick="createRandomArray()">Click Me</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue is you might get duplicates in your randomized gamespicked array. It might be better to shuffle the array (randomize it) and then just get the `slice` of X items, like this. Notice that I change the `numOfGames` value from a string to a number by prepending it with `+`

```
/* Randomize array in-place using Durstenfeld shuffle algorithm */
function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
}    
const boardGames = ["UNO", "Monopoly", "Clue", "Pandemic", "Catan", "Articulate!", "Codenames", "Fallout", "Candy Land", "Scrabble"];    
function createRandomArray () {
   let numOfGames = +document.getElementById("numOfGames").value || 0;
   let gamesPicked = shuffleArray(boardGames).slice(0, numOfGames)
   alert(gamesPicked.join("\n"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using vanilla JS like this

```
function samples(array, length) {
    var samplesSet = new Set();
    if (array.length < length) {
        throw Error("requested length is greater than given array");    
    }
    while(samplesSet.size < length) {
        samplesSet.add(array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)]);
    }
    return [...samplesSet];
}
function createRandomArray () {

var numOfGamesElement = document.getElementById("numOfGames");
var numOfGames = numOfGamesElement.value;

  const boardGames = ["UNO", "Monopoly", "Clue", "Pandemic", "Catan", "Articulate!", "Codenames", "Fallout", "Candy Land", "Scrabble"];


let gamesPicked = samples(boardGames, numOfGames);
  alert(gamesPicked.join("\n"));
//createTable(gamesPicked)
}
```

Or using [lodash](https://lodash.com/) [sampleSize](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sampleSize) like this

```
let _ = require('lodash');

function createRandomArray () {

var numOfGamesElement = document.getElementById("numOfGames");
var numOfGames = numOfGamesElement.value;

  const boardGames = ["UNO", "Monopoly", "Clue", "Pandemic", "Catan", "Articulate!", "Codenames", "Fallout", "Candy Land", "Scrabble"];


let gamesPicked = _.sampleSize(boardGames, numOfGames);
  alert(gamesPicked.join("\n"));
//createTable(gamesPicked)
}
```